# Merging consecutive rows in R dataframe if columns are same

Tags: perl, r

I am trying to convert one of my Perl script to R script. I have a dataframe in R which looks like (Ignore the column names)-

```
CHR     START          END      TYPE
chr1    945493         945593   normal
chr1    945593        947374    normal
chr1    947374        947474    normal
chr1    947474        947574    gain
chr1    947574        947674    gain
chr1    947674        960364    gain
chr1    960364        960464    normal
chr22   17290491    17290591    normal
chr22   17290591    17290691    normal
chr22   17290691    17290791    gain
chr22   17290791    17292513    gain
chr22   17292513    17292613    gain
chr22   17292613    17292713    gain
chr22   17292713    17293046    gain
chr22   17293346    17298475    gain
chr22   17298475    17298575    gain
chr22   17298575    17298675    normal
chr22   17298675    17303632    normal
chr22   17303632    17303732    loss
chr22   17303732    17303832    normal
chrX    154162621   154181221   normal
chrX    154181221   154181321   normal
chrX    154181321   154181421   loss
chrX    154181421   154181521   loss
chrX    154181521   154181621   loss
chrX    154181621   154181721   loss
chrX    154181721   154216867   loss
chrX    154216867   154216967   normal
chrX    154216967   154217067   normal
chrX    154217067   154217167   normal
```

If at least 5 continuous rows have same value in "CHR" column and "TYPE" column, then combine all those rows in one row so that START column should have value of first row and END column have value of last row and in the end just return rows which have "gain" or "loss" TYPE. So the desired output is:

```
chr22   17290691        17298575        gain
chrX    154181321       154216867       loss
```

What I am doing right now is:

1. Saving the dataframe with "write.table".
2. Use this perl script:

   ```
     open $first, "<",$ARGV[0] or die "Unable to open input file: $!";
     my $count=1;
     $_ = <$first>;
     chomp;
     my ($p_key, $p_col1, $p_col2,$p_cnv) = split;

     while(<$first>) {
         chomp;
         my ($key, $col1, $col2,$cnv) = split;
         if ($key eq $p_key and $cnv eq  $p_cnv) {
           $p_col2 = $col2;
           $count++;

         } elsif ($count > 4){


            print $p_key,"\t", $p_col1,"\t", $p_col2,"\t", $p_cnv,"\n" if($p_cnv eq "gain" or $p_cnv eq "loss");
            ($p_key, $p_col1, $p_col2, $p_cnv) = ($key, $col1, $col2, $cnv);
            $count=1;
           }

          else { 

       ($p_key, $p_col1, $p_col2, $p_cnv) = ($key, $col1, $col2, $cnv);
           $count=1;
          }
   }
   ```

I think this is an extra step to save the dataframe first and then use Perl script. Could anyone please suggest an easier way to do this in R - any package or any other trick?

Comment: As a first step, why not simply translate the Perl script into R (seems like fairly straight forward code), and see if you run into any problems?

Comment: That is what I want to do. It seems easy in Perl but I can't figure out how should I do it in R.

Comment: In your perl script you use `&` (bitwise AND) instead of `&&` (C-style logical AND). I would recommend using `or` and `and` instead, since they are more transparent and also have a lower precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was concerned that you should want to interrupt the sequences (i.e. consider them as distinct ) if there were intervening alternate values for TYPE within one chromosome. You didn't specifically state it as such but I think the biology would warrant that additional requirement. Hence the need for another variable to be created. We will assume the dataframe is named `cdat`, in the absence of advice to the contrary. This looks within consecutive runs of TYPE, applies the test,  and binds the CHR and START at the beginning and the END and TYPE for the last element.

```
cdat$conseq <-cumsum(c(1, cdat$TYPE[-1] != cdat$TYPE[-length(cdat$TYPE)] ) )
do.call( rbind, 
    by(cdat, list(cdat$CHR, cdat$conseq), 
         function(df)
            if( NROW(df) >=5 & df$TYPE[1] %in% c("gain", "loss") ) {
                cbind(df[1, c("CHR", "START")] , df[NROW(df), c("END", "TYPE")] ) 
                } else{NULL} ) )
     CHR     START       END TYPE
10 chr22  17290691  17298575 gain
23  chrX 154181321 154216867 loss
```

The conseq vector is built up by comparing the next TYPE value to its prior value and cumsum()-ing the appearance of a new value along its full length. Since those variables are one element shorter. the 1 is added as a placeholder at the beginning to let it line up with the dataframe.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. Could you please tell me little bit about first line? I think (as you said) you are creating new variable.

Comment: It sums changes in values of TYPE. The comparison or calculation with subset of vectors that have been shifted by one position is fairly common data manipulation strategy in R. See above.

Comment: AAh! I think I got it. With first line of code, you are creating this variable to assign same numbers to same TYPE if they are consecutive.

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines?

```
library(plyr)
ddply(x[x$TYPE %in% c("gain", "loss"), ], 
      .(CHR, TYPE), 
      function(z){if(nrow(z) < 5) NULL else z[range(seq_len(nrow(z))), ]}
      )

    CHR     START       END TYPE
1 chr22  17290691  17290791 gain
2 chr22  17298475  17298575 gain
3  chrX 154181321 154181421 loss
4  chrX 154181721 154216867 loss
```

Comment: +1 Using `range` on row numbers for that purpose is wonderfully slick. Except it appears he want only one row. I also wondered if runs of "gain" or "loss" that were interrupted by other values should be considered part of the same section. At the moment your method would lump all those together.

Comment: @DWin Thank you. And, yes, to be honest I didn't try to get a perfect understanding of the OP's requirement, nor to produce a perfect result. But I see what you mean now. I might edit this answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with SQL and want to do a lot of manipulation of data frames, another option is the [`sqldf`](https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/) library, which allows you to execute SQL queries on R dataframes.  It makes operations like this very easy.

There is also the [R-Perl interface](http://www.omegahat.org/RSPerl/), which would allow you to keep your existing Perl code, and then do R things with the result.